# Add coupon code in the subscription mail, Magento 1.9

Tags: email-templates, newsletter, coupon, coupon-codes

Can I add an automatic coupon code in the newsletter subscription mail.

I want everyone who signs up to newsletter receive a subscription mail with a coupon code that I automatically generated previously. It's possbile?

This is an example of what I want to do.

[image]

Comment: did you get solution for this? I am also facing same issue.